# ASIDownloadCache clear all but some items

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, caching, asihttprequest

I used [ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] to cache my HTTP requests, and at specific condition I have to do garbage collection for the some of cached requests.
I have a list of URLs to be kept in the cache and all other cached URLs (not in the list) should be cleared.

After checking I found that I have only two choices:

1. [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] removeCachedDataForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]]; : which deletes the cache for specific URL.
2. [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] clearCachedResponsesForStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];: which clear the entire cache for specific storage policy.

Both of them doesn't cover my requirement.

Any Suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there is no way in ASI, I suggest to go for AFNetworking.